# Hardware certification

Tags: canonical, hardware-certification

I bought a new laptop Dell - Latitude - 9410 2 in 1 with Windows 10. I want to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS wich is my main OS. I will use the two OS with a dual boot. But I saw that this laptop is not yet certified by Canonical! What am supposed to do? Thanks

Comment: The Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LiveUSB has a "Try Ubuntu" environment precisely so you can test your hardware. Pay close attention to testing your video card, GPU, and networking hardware. Take your time and be thorough.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Live CD option when booting the ISO to check if everything works fine. If it does, you should be able to use a full install of Ubuntu.